# How to clear the Emacs buffer history?

Tags: emacs

When I press `C-x b` (`ido-switch-buffer`) I get a lot of buffers that I don't want to see. I'd like to clear the buffer history.

I tried evaluating this expression (using `M-x eval-buffer`):

```
(setq ido-buffer-history '())
```

And it took effect; I can tell because I looked at the variable with `C-h v ido-buffer-history`. However, the change did not get reflected in the minibuffer when I press `C-x b`.

What else should I do? Are there other variables I should be clearing?

**UPDATE** : The 'extra' buffers that I'm seeing are *not* active. Interestingly, `C-x C-b` (`ido-fallback-command`) shows exactly what I would expect. It is the buffer history that I'm interested in. (See the `buffer-name-history` and `ido-buffer-history` variables for more context.)

Note: Perhaps it will help to mention that I'm using the emacs-starter-kit which has `ido-ubiquitous` installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following to your init.el: `(setq ido-use-virtual-buffers nil)`

---

*For posterity:*

Those are all the active buffers in your session. You can clean them with the following commands:

- `M-x clean-buffer-list` will close any clean buffers you haven't used in a while
- `M-x kill-some-buffers` will visit each buffer and ask if you want to close it
- `M-x kill-matching-buffers` will prompt for a regex over buffer names, which you can just leave blank

Edit:
There's also the boring old buffer menu you get with `C-x C-b`. In this menu, you can hold `d` until it marks each buffer for deletion, then press `x` to commit.

Comment: `M-x clean-buffer-list` didn't do it for me. `C-x b` still shows buffers that are not open, such as `ido-ubiquitous-autoloads.el`.

Comment: Ok, there are some other commands you can use, see updated answer.

Comment: Your answer gives various suggestions on how to close buffers, but that isn't what I need. All (or almost all) all my buffers are closed. My buffer name history contains buffers that are not open -- that is the issue here.

Comment: I'm using `ido-switch-buffer` too, those commands work for me. Anything suspect in your init.el?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Chris, I learned about ido's virtual buffers. I don't want to disable `ido-use-virtual-buffers` altogether. I want to clear the history as needed; these commands accomplish that goal:

```
(setq ido-virtual-buffers '())
(setq recentf-list '())
```

(Note that clearing `ido-virtual-buffers` was not sufficient -- `recentf-list` also must be cleared.)

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/MinibufferHistory) entry on emacswiki.

The variable that stores the buffer history you are referring to is `buffer-name-history`

If you run `M-x describe-variable RET buffer-name-history RET` you will see all of the dead buffers that no longer really exist. The wiki recommends creating a hook that removes the buffer name from the list whenever you kill a buffer.

I just did: `M-x eval-expression RET (setq buffer-name-history '()) RET`

This seems to have worked. The next time I ran C-x b I only cycled-through my *real* buffers.

That said, setting the variable to nil seems to completely disable the functionality (the variable doesn't seem to be re-populated once I open more buffers).