# How to prevent a fram show up for a second when emacsclient or `emacs -nw` starts?

Tags: emacs, daemon

I am using `emacs-daemon`. When every I restart my daemon and do `C-x C-b` my `Buffer List` seems always full.

Later, when I start my `emacsclient` for a seconds(like a fast flash) it shows a file that located on the top of my `Buffer List` and opens the file I want to open. This is little annoying to face with all the time.

Example:

- I type `emacsclient -t file_a.py`.
- For a second or less, buffer called `file_b.py` opens (my lastly opened file).
- Than `file_a.py` get opens.

### [image]

This always repeats itself even I clean my buffer list doing following and open a new file (since buffer list now contains more than one file):

[Link:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14151947/2402577)

> Edit: There's also the boring old buffer menu you get with `C-x C-b`.
>   In this menu, you can hold d until it marks each buffer for deletion,
>   then press x to commit.

Even after doing this after that `IBuffer` shows up since it is the latest opened buffer.

**[Q]** Is it possible to prevent 1 second file show up when I start `emacsclient`? If possible I always want to keep my `Buffer List` empty, but not sure would it be a good idea, or some how keep a empty file at the top of the buffer list since it will show a blank frame.

This also occurs when I using `emacs -nw` where `scratch*` buffer or latest opened buffer shows up for as seconds as well.